# VB.NET function that writes a specific value to a CSV

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

I have a `CSV` file that looks like this:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
H,I,J,K,L,M,N
O,P,Q,R,S,T,U
V,W,X,Y,Z,foo,bar
```

I would like to write a function that when given a row number and column number would be able to change its respective value within a CSV file saved on the computer.

For example, if given the `row` number of `3` and the `column` number of `4` and the value to change to as "test" then it would change the value of "Q" in the current `csv` to "test".

I've originally attempted to slowly increment specific numbers on a variable containing the `row` and `column` values (such as multiplying the row number by 2 to find the specific character in the CSV) but  each value in the CSV isn't always one character so that method wouldn't work. (such as `foo` and `bar` in the example above).

I've searched online already but I didn't find any examples that would change a value in a `csv` when provided a `row` and `column` number.

Is there any type of function that can be created so when provided a `row` and `column` number and a value would change a specific value in a `csv`?

*(If applicable, I would rather not create a new `csv` from the old one but to change the old one directly).*

Comment: Typically, unless you have fixed-size records you need to read and write the entire file in this situation.

Comment: Can't it work because the records are separated by a comma though?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It may still be fine if another file had to be written, but I'm repeating this process quit a bit (2 times every second to once every two seconds) so I don't think It would be most efficient to delete the old file and replace it again.

Comment: Since you're settings values that end up changing the files size, you have to rewrite the whole thing. If you don't want this, then change your storage strategy and pick, e.g., a light database.

Comment: @Jimi I've been thinking that loading the CSV into a ``DataGridView`` would be an easier way since I do manipulate ~700 values every second and repeat that. I guess thats the only efficient strategy left.

Comment: Loading you data in a DataGridView doesn't provide any form of permanent storage. You're handling your data in memory, the Control is only used to present the data to the User, only useful if presentation is a required feature and User interaction is not allowed (since the Control is updated each second). -- Your question is about storage, not presentation. You could manipulate the data in memory in any case. Data storage is a different topic.

Comment: If it's something where you're updating 700 values every second, processing a csv is defiantly the wrong way to go about it.  The disk access alone would be a limiting factor.  At that rate of change, I would even be questioning using a DataGridView due to the requirement of updating the UI.  IMO, you will be far better doing this in some light weight in memory collection

Comment: Do you at least have any good recommendations/suggestion on where to start for processing this type of heavy data in the memory or elsewhere though?

Comment: If it was me, I would define a class with properties for the data you read from the csv and a key (eg record number) then reading your file I would add instances of that class to a list, then it's a simple linq query to find your target record and update the required property

Comment: DataGridView is **not** the efficient strategy. Not even close. The efficient strategy is building a class to match the properties in the CSV file, loading the file to RAM once as a generic list of your new class type (assuming the file isn't too large), and then writing the changes once at the end. Or if it's a long-running system then use a database.